# JMeter replace all CRLF in the request body with LF

Tags: replace, jmeter

I am new to JMeter, I want to replace all CRLF characters with LF in the JMeter HTTP request body before it is sent to the server.
I need to do this for all requests in a thread group. Can someone please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, JMeter .jmx scripts are basically XML files so you can change CRLF to LF using any suitable text editor, even [Notepad++ is capable of doing it](https://superuser.com/questions/545461/replace-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-notepad)

If you're still looking for a JMeter-only solution - you can do it by adding a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) at the [same level](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) as your HTTP Request samplers and putting the following code into "Script" area:

```
def data = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue().replaceAll('\r\n', '\n')
def argument = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', data, '')
def arguments = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
arguments.addArgument(argument)
sampler.setArguments(arguments)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)